# Delphi roaming folder, registry access

Tags: delphi, winapi

I developed an application and I want to deploy it on one machine of my client network.
this machine turns under win7 64 bits and needs an admin authorization (they use active directory, GPO,...) so far no problem.
i am using the roaming folder to store some files.
the problem is when I launch the application it seems that it doesn't find the correct current user roaming folder path, I think that's redirected to the admin roaming folder.
my code is as follow

```
Function GetRoamingFolderPath():String;
var
 OsVersion: integer;
 Path: String;
begin
 OsVersion:=(TOSVersion.Major);
if OsVersion < 6 then
 Path:= GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA)
else
 path:= GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA);
end;
```

where GetSpecialFolderPath is defined as :

```
function GetSpecialFolderPath(folder : integer) : string;
 const   SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
 var path: array [0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
 if SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0,folder,0,SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,@path[0]))      
  then Result := path
else
 Result := '';
end;
```

also I need to register some values on registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER , it's done but my application can't access them !

any idea on how to resolve this 2 issues.
thanks.

Comment: Don't you think it would be reasonable to check what error codes you get if any?

Comment: for the registry I'm getting : no key found  and the same thing for the folder

Comment: We deal with one question at a time, since you provided no code for the registry access, let's focus on the folder issue. Post a new question for the registry issue. What error number does `SHGetFolderPath()` return? What does the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) say about the meaning of the code? Btw, `SHGetFolderPath()` is deprecated, do you need to support OS's before Vista?

Comment: In addition to what @Tom asked, it's also necessary for roaming profiles to be enabled on your server and workstations; it's not automatic. Roaming profiles makes the default location for the AppData\Roaming folder a network path that is available from everywhere on your network. If that isn't enabled, then trying to use roaming profiles will not work.

Comment: There's no question here. Have you contemplated doing some debugging rather than throwing your hands up and hoping we'll write your program for you. Inspect return values and debug like a programmer would.

Comment: @TomBrunberg i had wrapped my function into a try catch block and I'm getting only this custom message : Directory not found and yes I would like to support older OS's before vista (my app is also 32 bits)

Comment: @KenWhite what folder should I use instead of roaming

Comment: @DavidHeffernan of course I do, What do you think, I don't need any thing from your part.

Comment: These functions don't raise exceptions. So Try/Except is pointless. But hey, you already know that right? You don't need anything from me!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I used inside : raise Exception.create(format('...)) and if you can't help others for any reason don't waste your time to tell them such things

Comment: Not according to the code here. You don't inspect the return value beyond checking it with SUCCEEDED. Does the call succeed? If so what is returned. If not, what is the error code? If you have debugged, you know these facts. We don't. Honestly, some simple debugging would have told you what was wrong. Don't give up so easily.

Comment: Now I don't follow you sorry. You seem to speak about code you have not shown, and messages that are triggered by what criteria? I suggest you step back for a while, do some actual debugging and return when you have more facts.

Answer (score 3):

```
Function GetRoamingFolderPath():String;
var
 OsVersion: integer;
 Path: String;
begin
 OsVersion:=(TOSVersion.Major);
if OsVersion < 6 then
 Path:= GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA)
else
 path:= GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA);
end;
```

This function assigns to the local variable `path`, but not the return value. Hence its return value is undefined. Remove the variable `path` and assign to `Result` instead.

```
function GetRoamingFolderPath: string;
begin
  if TOSVersion.Major < 6 then
    Result := GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA)
  else
    Result := GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA);
end;
```

This would have been obvious had you stepped through the code under the debugger and inspected the intermediate values. You would have observed that `GetSpecialFolderPath` returned the desired value, but that it got lost in `GetRoamingFolderPath`. Once you had made that observation, it would have become obvious what the fault was. I urge you to debug like this in future when you encounter such problems.